# one mvc form contains dropdowns with same id

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

My MVC form has two drop-down that have identical id and name.  The back-end data table has only one field to take the selected value.  The field is associated with a look-up table that contains all the values in these drop-down.  Each of the two drop-down contain only a subset of the values based on their usage type.  I do this so that I can use jQuery on the client side to show the drop-downs mutual exclusively. For example, when a non-blank selection is made in first drop-down the script will hide the second drop-down, and vice versa.  If a blank option is selected in either drop-down, both drop-down will be shown.  Since the post back form would contain an array with two items.  Will the default binder automatically bind to the array item that contains non-blank value? If this is not the right way to do this, I appreciate any suggestions.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your view code where you render dropdowns?

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle this in one of two different ways:

1. Create a view model that has the two optional fields in it and
   properly name and id your form fields.  It is not valid to have
   multiple elements with the same ID and you're opening the door to have a 
   tough time later with jQuery selectors anyways.
2. The other option is to use jQuery to submit the form via Ajax.
   Again, to have valid HTML, properly name the forms, but when 
   you pass the values in the Ajax request, you're only going to
   assign the one with the value you're looking for.

As a side note, and I'm not sure if this works with your design, but you could also explore the idea of having *only* one drop down and populate the drop down with the sub set of results  that are valid for the context.  You could, for example, let the user pick path A/B with a button group using something like Twitter.Bootstrap: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons

Cheers.